# How Can I Automate the Change between a Python Script and a Nohup Python Script?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, python, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to a digital temperature probe, which measures my fermenting beer. A python script reads the temperature every second and prints it to the console, and stores it in a MySQL database.

I enjoy and benefit from watching the temperature from the console on my computer over SSH during the day time. However, during the night, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and run the following:

```
nohup python thermometer.py
```

Which allows me to shut down my SSH and my computer while retaining the temperature gathering. At 7am I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and then run the following:

```
phython thermometer.py
```

I do not wish to do this manually any more.

I would prefer some type of script that simply issued the `nohup` command at 12am and returned to the normal `python` command at 7am.

How can I do this in the most "linux appropriate" manner?

I am pretty new to Linux; for example, I learned of the nohup command on the RPi stackexchange...

I guess that either a modified python script issuing an `os` command or a batch script would be most appropriate.

Comment: Have you thought about running the script in `tmux` or `screen` and attaching/detatching? (+1 for the first sentence of this question)...

Comment: Honestly I am ignorant of `tmux` or `screen`, but thank you I will look them up!

Comment: @jasonwryan   
Honestly I am ignorant of tmux or screen, but thank you I will look them up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the script with `nohup python thermometer.py &` it will write the output to nohup.out file.

So whenever you want to read the output use `tail -f nohup.out`. (You don't have to kill the process every time or automate to change the nohup)

Comment: The very similar alternative is to redirect the process output to a log file, eg `nohup python thermometer.py > logfile 2>&1 &`.  You can then simply log in at any time and "follow" the log file.  Basically you are turning the script into a basic "service".

Comment: Manula, the `tail -f nohup.out` command reveals the database warnings I always see when I run python thermometer1.py but it is not revealing the print commands for some reason? Interestingly, when I hit `ctrl+c` in the nohup window, the `tail` window then prints out the last 10 lines of temperatures and the python error message from the `KeyboardInterrupt`. Any speculations? In addition, if I `ctrl+c` and then issue `tail -f nohup.out` again I only see the database warnings but not the print output. I am printing to the console via python's `print` command.

Comment: @Johan by following the logfile do you mean issuing `tail -f logfile`? If so, I am getting the same problem as with the comment above.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen You can use `nohup python print.py 2> /dev/null 1> out.log &` tail the out.log file